# Postgres column named with numbers

Tags: postgresql

I simple typo, but I named a table in my postgres database with all number.... now I can't delete it. And all sorts of issues surround this simple mistake, including being denied permission to export the database. Does anyone have a solution so that I can get full control of my DB back??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use double quotes around the table name?

Comment: How did you create it? I mean if you managed to create it, you'd either know about quoting and would have dropped it the same way or used some tool and would have also used that for dropping.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You mean `DROP TABLE "12345";`, right? But the "permission denied" during `pg_dump` means that the table is owned by a different user than the one who tries to dump the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, Double quotes was the solution.

I didn't create it using quotes, so I wouldn't have known to use quotes to remove it. And in researching it, there was no mention of using quotes. I'm surprised that it would let me create it if it's an illegal table name (all Numbers).